# How to pass the data from child to parent? when parent is class based and child is functional based

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to pass the data which is anything like, array, strings, numbers into the App(Parent) Component) from the Child1(Child) components.

There's a parent who is class-based and the child is functional based.

**Parent:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Child1 from "./Child1/Child1";



class App extends Component {
  state = { message: "" };

  callbackFunction = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      message: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child1 />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Child**

```
import React from 'react'

const Child1 = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Child1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded another solution for you using combine Functional-Class-functional component pass data. here the live code for [https://codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/child-to-parent-data-pass-with-combine-class-and-functional-component-824ce) Click and check that.

#### Also same code added bellow here:

**app component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import Child from "./child";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Orignal Button");
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = _name => {
    setName(_name);
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const resetClick = e => {
    setName("Orignal Button");
    setCount(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Child
        name={name + " - " + count}
        handleClick={handleClick}
        resetClick={resetClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**child1 component**

```
import React from "react";

import Child2 from "./child2";

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h2>This is child</h2>
        <button onClick={e => this.props.handleClick("New Name changed")}>
          {this.props.name}
        </button>
        <Child2 handleChilc2Click={this.props.resetClick} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

**Another component Child2**

```
import React from "react";

const Child2 = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Child 2</h2>
      <button onClick={e => props.handleChilc2Click(e)}>
        Click me for reset Parent default
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Child2;
```

You can some help from it.
**Thanks**

Comment: Same problem as Ramesh, but Ramesh solved in the answer. If you just add a duplicate answer maybe the answer should improve on what's already there instead of providing a lesser solution.

Comment: It's not Duplicate you plz see it's another answer for the functional component to Class Component to the functional component, it's one of Visevarsa data pass

Comment: And another thing another solve it using React.memo but my answer is not to use it.

Comment: How is your answer different then the one I already gave (Parent is class Child is functional)? And you also added a performance hit by forcing React to update DOM on unrelated prop changes because you pass a new reference to a prop (onClick) on every render (see discussion under Ramesh answer). If you fix this then you end up with the exact same answer I gave, unless you fix it with `useCallback` instead of `React.memo`. I'll upvote if you demonstrate `useCallback` to prevent `onClick={new=>reference}`

Comment: @HMR you are thinking right, but my answer showed them how to communicate children to parent pass data. it isn't the same as Ramesh answer but it is another way to communicate one to another related as this ask. Hopefully, Your acceptance is heigh from this Ask.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to send some data to the parent component upon clicking a button that's in the child component, you can do it this way:

```
import React from 'react'

const Child1 = React.memo((props) => {
    return (
        <div>
         <button onClick={() => {props.clicked('some data')}} type="button">Click me to send data<button>
        </div>
    );
})

export default Child1;
```

now you can assign a function to the clicked prop in your parent component and that gets called when the button in the child component is clicked:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { message: "" };

  callbackFunction = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      message: event.target.value
    });
  }
  
  clicked = (data) => { // this func. will be executed
   console.log(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child1 clicked={this.clicked}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Assigning a prop with a new reference on every render is devastating to performance and will have virtual DOM compare fail on every render so you'll force React to do needless DOM updates. So please don't do `prop={(new)=>reference}` or `prop={{new:'reference'}}`. Instead you should try to do `prop={this.member}` or use hooks like useMemo, useCallback the likes for functional components.

Comment: @HMR that's true. I simply wanted to show how he can transfer the data. Anyway updated my answer.

Comment: Still fails on virtual dom compare because `const clicked = () => {` creates a new reference and functional components will always re render. It works if you do `const Child1 = React.memo( function Child1(props) {`

Comment: @HMR so for this scenario we can't avoid using `React.memo`?

Comment: React.memo is needed because then it won't even go into virtual DOM compare (or if it does it'll not produce new jsx because React.memo produces a pure component). When you leave it as is then Child1 is a functional component and always produce new jsx every time Parent renders (even when Parent renders for reasons unrelated to Child1). Because the new Child1 jsx has a onClick property with a new reference it'll fail virtual DOM compare and React will do a DOM update for Child1.

Comment: Yep, I know how `React.memo` works. I'm just asking if there is an alternate way instead of using React.memo or useMemo hook.

Comment: Other ways to fix this is to use the `useCallback` hook in Child1, or set a custom property on the element: `<button data-id={someId} onClick={props.onClick}` and in the Parent: `onClick=e=>doSomething(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'))` but custom attributes can only have strings so this will complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to Child (called Counter in the example) that will change Parent state. Since you pass the same reference for this function every time (this.increment) the only Children that will render are those that changed.

```js
const Counter = React.memo(
  //use React.memo to create pure component
  function Counter({ counter, increment }) {
    console.log('rendering:', counter.id)
    // can you gues why prop={new reference} is not a problem here
    //  this won't re render if props didn't
    //  change because it's a pure component
    return (
      <div>
        <div>counter is {counter.count}</div>
        <button onClick={() => increment(counter.id)}>
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
)

class Parent extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, count: 0 },
      { id: 2, count: 0 }
    ]
  }
  increment = _id =>
    this.setState({
      counters: this.state.counters.map(val =>
        _id === val.id
          ? { ...val, count: val.count + 1 }
          : val
      )
    })
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
          <Counter
            counter={counter}
            increment={this.increment}
            key={counter.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

//render app
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```