# dynamically generated Toggle (switches) in react js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

There are two types of switch status in my project. One is default and the other is generated from API.When the item is changed toggle switch on/off won't work.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      switch_status: [true, false],
      items: [{title:toyota}, {title:bmw}]
    }
}
```

There is a function, Which get data from API and set into items:

```
 changeItems = () => {
  this.setState({ items: [{title:toyota, switch_status: true},
                         {title:porche, switch_status: true}, 
                         {title:bmw, switch_status: false}] 
              });
  }
```

on/off not working, When Items changed:

```
//Switch on/off function
handleChange = (event, id) => {

    const isChecked = event;
    this.setState(
      ({switch_status}) => ({
          switch_status: {
              ...switch_status,
              [id]: isChecked,
          }
      })
  );    
}

//Loop Items
this.state.items.map((item, index) => (

              <Switch
                className="custom-switch custom-switch-primary"
                checked={this.state.switch_status[index]}
                id={index}
                onChange={event => handleChange(event, index)}

              />

))
```

Comment: Are you maintaining "switch_status" under state directly or under each item?

Comment: switch_status is an object when you set state but an array when you initialise state. Then there is state.items that is an array of objects that has switch_status in there in setState but not when you initialize the state.

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara Initially,The "switch_status" directly under state but when we click on **changeItems()** function, The switch status will be under each items.

Comment: @HMR exactly that's a confusion.

Comment: Why would you duplicate information in your state and have switch_states in state.items[item] and in state.switch_state[item]? I provided an answer that only stores switch_state once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your state handling logic really but your **componentDidUpdate()** is getting called infinite times because the check inside  is not working and it overwrites your toggle state even when you don't need to.

Change you **componentDidUpdate()** to:

```
componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
    if (
      JSON.stringify(previousProps.mediaTypes.items) !==
      JSON.stringify(this.props.mediaTypes.items)
    ) {
      this.dataListRender();
      this.setState({
        customMediaTypesItems: this.props.mediaTypes.items.custom_media_types
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all; you are passing a new reference to a component as prop on every render and that causes [needless DOM updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595621/how-to-pass-the-data-from-child-to-parent-when-parent-is-class-based-and-child/60601500?noredirect=1#comment107216296_60601500)

Second is that you initialise the state with a different structure than when you are setting state. I assume that

```
{
  items: [
    { title: toyota, switch_status: true },
    { title: porche, switch_status: true },
    { title: bmw, switch_status: false }
  ];
}
```

Is your actual state because you use that to render. You can do the following:

```js
const Switch = React.memo(
  //use React.memo to create pure component
  function Switch({ label, checked, toggle, id }) {
    console.log("rendering:", label);
    // prop={new reference} is not a problem here
    //  this won't re render if props didn't
    //  change because it's a pure component
    //  if any of the props change then this needs to re render
    return (
      <label>
        {label}
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => toggle(id)}
        />
      </label>
    );
  }
);

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    items: [
      { title: "toyota", switch_status: true },
      { title: "porche", switch_status: true },
      { title: "bmw", switch_status: false }
    ]
  };
  toggle = _index =>
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
        _index === index // only toggle the item at this index
          ? { ...item, switch_status: !item.switch_status }
          : item // do not change the item
      )
    });
  render() {
    //please note that using index is not a good idea if you
    //  change the order of the state.items, add or remove some item(s)
    //  if you plan to do that then give each item a unique id
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
          <Switch
            label={item.title}
            checked={item.switch_status}
            toggle={this.toggle}
            id={index}
            key={index}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//render app
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue while getting the checked state.
In your current implementation, you have written `const isChecked = event;` in the `handleChange` method which will always be true since the `event` object is always available.

It should be `const isChecked = event.target.checked;` for it to set the toggled checkbox state correctly.